# How do you get Accuracy, Precision and Recall using R and homals?

Tags: r, classification, binary-data, predict, precision-recall

I have used the R package homals (Multiple correspondence analysis, Homogeneity analysis) to evaluate a classification model with binary data only. I get the following result:

```
> pr.res
Classification rate:
     Variable Cl. Rate %Cl. Rate
1  Variable_01   0.9952     99.52
2  Variable_02   0.9472     94.72
3  Variable_03   0.8897     88.97
4  Variable_04   1.0000    100.00
5  Variable_05   0.9784     97.84
6  Variable_06   0.8945     89.45
7  Variable_07   0.8609     86.09
8  Variable_08   0.8849     88.49
9  Variable_09   0.9520     95.20
10 Variable_10   0.8897     88.97
11 Variable_11   0.9017     90.17
12 Variable_12   0.8705     87.05
13 Variable_13   0.8705     87.05
14 Variable_14   0.8849     88.49
15 Variable_15   0.7314     73.14
16 Variable_16   0.8633     86.33
17 Variable_17   0.8945     89.45
18 Variable_18   0.8825     88.25
```

Here it seems Variable_04 is the best and Variable_15 is the worst performing. To me, all these classification rates appear very reasonable in the context.

Then I found two webpages which discuss *Accuracy* as well as *Precision* and *Recall*.

- https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/accuracy
- https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/precision-and-recall

They argue that Accuracy is not enough (i.e. my *Classification Rate*). Therefore, I would also like to examine Precision and Recall. I can *see* the underlying values for calculating them (TP[True Positive], FP, TN, FN) but am at loss how to retrieve them as an object:

```
>summary(pr.res)
Classification Tables (observed vs. predicted): 

Variable: Variable_01 
   pre
obs   0   1
  0  23   0
  1   2 392

Variable: Variable_02 
   pre
obs   0   1
  0  31   2
  1  20 364
[...]
```

How would I calculate *Accuracy*, *Precision* and *Recall* with this binary dataset? Are there perhaps more useful packages in R? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use `caret::confusionMatrix`. Visit [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/confusionMatrix.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll lok into that!

Comment: Also try `SUM = summary(pr.res);   str(SUM)`